# Error: no member named '__fs' in namespace "std" when compiling omnet++ project with makefile

Tags: c++, makefile, omnet++, inet, satellite

I'm doing an project about satellite communication and need to simulate it in omnet++.

I use Omnet++ 6.0.1 and INET 4.4, the gcc version is 11.3.0, which natively support c++ 17 (and I already set the compiler in c++ 17 mode). The whole project is running in a virtual machine.

I tried to compile one project I found from the git repo (https://github.com/Avian688/leosatellites), but failed with Error: no member named '__fs' in namespace "std".

```
networklayer/configurator/ipv4/LeoIpv4NetworkConfigurator.cc
networklayer/configurator/ipv4/LeoIpv4NetworkConfigurator.cc:58:13: error: no member named '__fs' in namespace 'std'
    if(std::__fs::filesystem::is_directory(filePrefix) || std::__fs::filesystem::exists(filePrefix)) {
       ~~~~~^
networklayer/configurator/ipv4/LeoIpv4NetworkConfigurator.cc:58:64: error: no member named '__fs' in namespace 'std'
    if(std::__fs::filesystem::is_directory(filePrefix) || std::__fs::filesystem::exists(filePrefix)) {
                                                          ~~~~~^
networklayer/configurator/ipv4/LeoIpv4NetworkConfigurator.cc:180:15: error: no member named '__fs' in namespace 'std'
    if (!std::__fs::filesystem::is_directory(filePrefix) || !std::__fs::filesystem::exists(filePrefix)) {
         ~~~~~^
networklayer/configurator/ipv4/LeoIpv4NetworkConfigurator.cc:180:67: error: no member named '__fs' in namespace 'std'
    if (!std::__fs::filesystem::is_directory(filePrefix) || !std::__fs::filesystem::exists(filePrefix)) {
                                                             ~~~~~^
networklayer/configurator/ipv4/LeoIpv4NetworkConfigurator.cc:181:14: error: no member named '__fs' in namespace 'std'
        std::__fs::filesystem::create_directory(filePrefix);
        ~~~~~^
5 errors generated.
make: *** [Makefile:150: ../out/clang-release/src/networklayer/configurator/ipv4/LeoIpv4NetworkConfigurator.o] Error 1
```

I generated the makefile with the following command:

```
opp_makemake --make-so -f --deep -KINET4_4_PROJ=$HOME/omnetpp-6.0.1/samples/inet4.4 -KOS3_PROJ=$HOME/omnetpp-6.0.1/samples/os3 -DINET_IMPORT '-I/home/zzz/omnetpp-6.0.1/samples/leosatellites/src/igraph' '-I$(OS3_PROJ)/src' '-I$(INET4_4_PROJ)/src' '-I/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/curl' '-L/usr/lib' '-L$(INET4_4_PROJ)/src' '-L$(OS3_PROJ)/src' '-ligraph' '-lxml2 -lz' '-lgmp' '-lblas' '-lglpk' '-llapack' '-larpack' '-lINET$(D)' '-los3$(D)'
```

and make with:

```
make MODE=release && make MODE=debug
```

Theoretically, this error should not occur since I already compile the relative project os3 successfully (https://github.com/Avian688/os3) and all other needed packages are installed

I tried to delete all references with "__fs" in the c++ file since in c++17, std::filesystem works, but then new error occured: error: no member named 'filesystem' in namespace 'std'.

I also tried to include the <experimental/filesystem> .h file, which I found in other q&a, also doesn't work.

I used to use the namespace std::filesystem a lot but never came up with such problem, could any one figure it out?

Comment: Replacing all instances of `std::__fs::filesystem` with just `std::filesystem` ought to work. Can you edit your question with an example of how that goes wrong?

Comment: @Botje Yes I tried it, the new error report is similar with the former five, but says there is no member "filesystem" in "std" * 5 times

Comment: In C++17 filesystem library is no longer experimental, you need `#include <filesystem>`, not `experimental`

Comment: Do the source files that use that have a line `#include <filesystem>` at the top to include the filesystem library of C++17? Also, with what options are the C++ files compiled? (If I remember correctly GCC 11.x needs an explicit `-std=c++17` or higher to switch to C++17 mode.)

Comment: @Botje other member in std like std::string works well since there is no error report about it. Only member std::filesystem could not be found.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen Yes you are right, I originally include <filesystem>. I use <experimental/filesystem> just for a try, although both of them don't works

Comment: Can you please show the full compiler commandline being used for that `LeoIpv4NetworkConfigurator.cc` file? I am fairly certain you just forgot the `-std=c++17` argument.

Comment: @chris_se Yes the head file <filesystem> is included with "#include <filesystem>", and c++ is specified in the omnet++ configure.user.dist file with "CXXFLAGS=-std=c++17"

Comment: @Botje of course. It's specified in the configure.user.dist file in the root of omnet++ with "CXXFLAGS=-std=c++17"

Comment: That is not the same as verifying. Please show the actual commandline being used to compile that file. It looks like you get that by doing `make V=1 MODE=release`

Comment: @Botje Ah, it's "make MODE=release && make MODE=debug" in the command line

Comment: Whichever of the two modes you were trying to get working. just add the `V=1`.

Comment: @Botje Thanks for you tips, but still got the same error. I compiled it with make V=1 MODE=release && make V=1 MODE=debug. But this time there is a long test before the error report, I 'll type it down below the next answer box

Comment: [Edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/75761707/edit) with the full output of that make command please. I really just need to know if `-std=c++17` is in the compiler invocation.

Comment: Well there's your problem. Complete lack of `-std=c++17` in the compiler commandline. As we guessed. It is also using `clang++` instead of `g++`...

Comment: @Botje I think that's where the problem is. But -std=c++17 is specified in this original configuration in line 50 of this file (https://github.com/omnetpp/omnetpp/blob/master/configure.user.dist), seems like it's default in c++17 mode and I didn't change it

Comment: You assume that the parent project is related to the example at all; I'm not so certain. As a quick fix hack the Makefile by adding `CXXFLAGS += -std=c++17` somewhere

Comment: @Botje The problem is perfectly solved by changing the compiler to gcc! The reason why I didn't solve it is because I didn't re compile the whole omnet++ after changing the configure.user (set the default compiler to gcc) to make the new configure of the compiler works! Thank you vvvvery much, you are my superman :)

Comment: Regardless, you should file a pull request that gets rid of the `std::__fs` so people with  compilers from this century can also compile the code.

Comment: @Botje Yes I mentioned it in the answer down below

Comment: Putting an answer on SO is not the same making an actual pull request to the GitHub repository.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is solved by @Botje. All I need to do is change the default compiler to gcc instead of clang in the configure.user file and recompile the whole omnet++. Then delete all the instances with "__fs" since I set `CXXFLAGS += -std=c++17` and it supports member std::filesystem. Then remake the leosatellite project, it works!